# A maximal subspace of the vector space of real valued function

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to find a maximal subspace of the vector space of real valued functions.

I've proved that the subspace $N_X=\{f:\mathbb{R\rightarrow\mathbb{R}}: f(r)=0\space\forall r\in X\}$ is maximal subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ when $X={\{r\}},$ without consider the whole space, but I am searching another maximal subspace $W,$ $W\neq N_{\{r\}}.$

I was thinking that subspace of odd or even function could work but I do not get anything useful.

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All we need is a nonzero linear function $h:\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}\to \Bbb R$ that has more complicated behavior than evaluation at $x_0\in\mathbb R$. Then, the kernel of $h$ will be a maximal subspace that does not belong to the list you have provided.

Here's an example. Let $h(f) = f(1)-f(0)$. One easily verifies $h$ is linear. We can also read off the maximal subspace: $\{f\in\mathbb R^{\mathbb R} | f(1)=f(0)\}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a while trying to prove  kernel of $h$ is maximal but I do not get it. Would you mind provide a hint to prove that?

Comment: @Suiz96 Sure. Recall/show that if $V$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$, then $h^{-1}(h(V))=V+\ker h$. So, if $V$ happens to contain $\ker h$, then $h^{-1}(h(V)) = V$. Now, $h(V)$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R$. What are the possibilities for $h(V)$? Then, deduce that $V=\ker h$ or $V=\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$.

Comment: Many thanks! That was so useful.

Comment: @user714630, Isn't the subspace of all linear functions $W=\{f \in \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} | f(x)=ax+b, \ a,b \in \mathbb{R} \}$ a maximal subspace ?

Comment: @Masmath That's an interesting idea. However, all linear functions are continuous, and the subspace of all continuous functions isn't even maximal. I'll leave that as an exercise, but feel free to ask for hints. A different way to look at this is to note that $W\cong \Bbb R^2$ but $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$ is infinite dimensional.

Comment: @user714630, Yeh,I see the set of all of 2nd degree polynomials contains my above set $W$ and hence not maximal. Am I right ?

Comment: @Masmath That also works, because there are functions that are not 2nd degree polynomials (e.g. a monic 3rd degree polynomial :))