# How do I show that $W_{x_0}$ is a maximal subspace of $\mathscr{C}(X, \mathbb{F})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $X$ be a set, $\mathbb{F}$ be a field, and $\mathscr{C}(X, \mathbb{F})$ denote the space of all functions on $X$. $W_{x_0}$ is defined as the set of all functions $f$ in $\mathscr{C}(X, \mathbb{F})$ such that $f(x_0) = 0$. Show that $W_{x_0}$ is a maximal subspace of $\mathscr{C}(X, \mathbb{F})$ $\forall x_0 \in X$, i.e. there is no proper subspace of $\mathscr{C}(X, \mathbb{F})$ containing $W_{x_0}$ properly.
>
> Is the converse true, i.e. is every maximal subspace of $\mathscr{C}(X, \mathbb{F})$ of the form $W_{x_0}$ for some $x_0 \in X$?

To begin, I showed that $W_{x_0}$ is a **proper** subspace of $\mathscr{C}(X, \mathbb{F})$.

However, I'm unable to take it from here. I intend to show the non-existence of a subspace $A$ of $\mathscr{C}(X, \mathbb{F})$ such that $A$ is a proper subspace of $\mathscr{C}(X, \mathbb{F})$, and $W_{x_0}$ is properly contained in it. How should I go about showing this without loss of generality?

Thanks!

P.S. I feel a little weird about this question, I think I may have a counterexample. This question's on my (ungraded) assignment though, so I'm probably incorrect. Here's my "counterexample" - consider a subspace $A$ of $\mathscr{C}(X, \mathbb{F})$ such that $\forall f \in A$, $f(x_0) = 0$ and $f(x_1) = 0$ ($x_1$ is some other, fixed element in $X$). I think that this $A$ is a proper subspace of $\mathscr{C}(X, \mathbb{F})$, and also properly contains $W_{x_0}$. What's wrong?

P.P.S.
My intuition says that the converse (the second part of the problem) is true, but I'm not sure. If it's not, could someone share a counterexample?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A maximal subspace of the vector space of real valued function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3479097/a-maximal-subspace-of-the-vector-space-of-real-valued-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Two ways to solve the question**

The first one is to use the general result that says that the kernel of a linear form is a maximal subspace.

Second one is to prove it in ou particular case. To do so, take $g \notin W_{x_0}$. By hypothesis, $g(x_0) \neq 0$. Now for any $f$

$$f=g \frac{f(x_0)}{g(x_0)}+ (f-g \frac{f(x_0)}{g(x_0)} )$$

Notice that $(f-g \frac{f(x_0)}{g(x_0)} )$ vanishes at $x_0$.

Comment: I haven't come across the first "general result" before. Could you elaborate on it further?
Moreover, I don't understand how the second solution works. Could you add some more details, please?

Comment: My last comment in the answer should be enough if you look at it carefully.

Comment: $f$ is any function in $\mathscr{C}(X, \mathbb{F})$, right? I see that the function you've constructed has a zero at $x_0$, hence lies inside $W_{x_0}$. However, $g \notin W_{x_0}$. Is that a contradiction of some sort? I apologize, but I'm unable to see how to take this further.

Comment: Yes, $f$ is any map. Can you recall what to be maximal means? This should enable you to understand.

Comment: I apologize, I'm unable to see it still. I request you to kindly elaborate/provide some more hints. From *maximal*, I understand that there is no proper subspace that properly contains $W_{x_0}$

Comment: Also, from your answer, I'm able to see that **any function** can be written as the sum of two functions, one in $W_{x_0}$, and one outside $W_{x_0}$.  How do I take it from here?

Comment: Important is that whatever map $g$ outside of $W_{x_0}$ you take, $W_{x_0}$ and this map $g$ span the whole space.